# Not sure what control in android should I use

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm new to android and I was hoping to get some minor non-coding help. Simply put I am continuously getting an image off from a server, but the problem is I'm not sure which control I should use. I know I can't use async task because it is used as a one time call and I can't use a service because I only want to run it on one activity alone. When the app closed or activity is changed the continuous process stops. Should I use thread, executor, future task or some other control?

**Edit:** Basically its going to be just like Async download image except it's going to call continuously while app is still on and the activity is the same as it is. Here is a sample of async download

http://javatechig.com/android/download-image-using-asynctask-in-android

Comment: Please provide more details and sample code in order for others to understand your problem effectively.

Answer (score 0):

For image processing you should most often use of of the various image processing libraries out there. Check out Picasso and Glide. They handle all threading and caching automatically for you.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score -1):

Get a image from service is about Android Network Programming .You can use HttpUrlConnection or HttpClient communicate with service,then you use JAVA stuffs,
like getting inputStream..Then use BitmapFactory.decodeStream() decode your inputStream and get a image from service.(Remember you must do network operation in child thread:)
Then use Handler let your bitmap show in your ImageView!
(I don't know if it can help you,forgive my bad English:);